# Where can I find Android Push Notification Settings in back4app

Tags: android, parse-platform, back4app

I'm trying to send a push notification to my app using Parse back{4}app by following [this](http://docs.back4app.com/docs/android/push-notification-2/) tutorial. But when I get to step 3, they say to edit android push notification settings in the dashboard, but I cannot find this option in my dashboard.

Another thing I didn't understand is the last part of step 1, changing the red code with my own. What am I supposed to change **this** to?

```
<category android:name="**dominwong4.scm.back4apppushnotificationcloudcode**" />
```

It's from from this code:

```
<!--
 IMPORTANT: Change "YOUR_SENDER_ID" to your GCM Sender Id.
 DON't DELETE the "id:"-->
 <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
 android:value="id:966437188652" />
 <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
 <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
 <category android:name="**dominwong4.scm.back4apppushnotificationcloudcode**" />
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
 <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
 <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
 <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change it to the package name of your application. There's a link at the top of that page to a github project.

If you look in there, you'd see code with

```
package dominwong4.scm.back4apppushnotificationcloudcode;
```

The instructions assume you've used a package name that identifies your own app when you created a project

Can't help with the dashboard... Haven't used Back4App

Comment: Thanks!! This seriously helped me ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the push notification settings, after the changes to Back4App's site, it's located by following these steps:

After Login in your Back4App Account, click on "Features" below your AppName. Then you'll search for "Android Push notification" and click on "Server". 
That should bring up the Push Notification settings for Android.

Checking the Online Chat is a great idea too, seems very useful.